# What auto-formatting Excel performs when copying data?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I am trying to move VBA functionality to .NET Excel Add-in project. 
This is a data import tool that does some data normalization before importing data. But I am having problems to understand data normalization that Excel is making automatically (to capture all the transformations that I need to re-implement in .NET side).

Specifically - Excel import file has range with strings, that has essentially numbers with thousand separators - now, copying this range in Excel using VBA script automatically converts these strings to numbers (and removes those thousand separators). For date time values there are very many automatic transformations to recognize date in string value.

I tried to find information on this auto-formatting (a list of what transformations are made on copying values from Excel to Excel), but so far I managed to find only some hacks on how to prevent auto-formatting, but no info on what exact formatting rules/logic is performed on string values.

Can anybody share this information?

Comment: I don't think VSTO should be behaving any differently than VBA in this respect. VSTO just builds on the same object model. Are you seeing differences?

Comment: @CindyMeister in this legacy Excel file value normalization is performed while Range is copied using VBA code (for instance thousand separator simbols are removed), I wander if there are other transformations that VBA Range copy `TargetRange.Value = SourceRange.Value` is performing? I was trying to do those transforms in code "manualy" just to have "control" over them - to know "what is going on", but thanks for the idea - I will check what happens with transformations if I copy Range in VSTO code